# How to check the logs for openstack-autopilot

Tags: juju, maas, landscape, openstack-autopilot

Trying to run the Landscape openstack install for Trusty.

I picked all my options in Landscape, then I hit install.
It seems the status is stuck trying to boostrap Juju. On MAAS the node is marked as deployed.

Where can I go check the status in logs.

I have to say so far it's a pain in the ass. Everything is hidden behind a shiny UI that says nothing and then you have to to go dig deep into some log.

Answer (score 1):

How long did you wait for bootstrap? It will fail on its own if it takes too long, and then the app will give you an option to file a bug with logs attached.

On to your specific question, though, the more interesting logs, if you want to watch details about an ongoing deployment, are on the `landscape-server/0` unit in `/var/log/landscape-server`. Specifically, `/var/log/landscape-server/job-handler.log`. That file will have details about the ongoing deployment.

Comment: Cool. I'll check it out. Curious. I already had juju boostrapped on another machine. Curious if I register that juju install in landscape will it skip that install part or will it try to install juju again? I made it all the way to the landscape UI picked all my openstack options, and then it timed out trying to install juju but I was able to SSH to the box.

Comment: No, landscape won't take advantage of an existing juju bootstrap node. It needs to control the process from the beginning.

Comment: Ah boo that's a shame! :(